# Return removed title bar of a QDockWidget for drag-ability

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

So we can remove a title bar of a `QDockWidget` like this:

```
self.dW1.setTitleBarWidget(QtGui.QWidget(self.dW1))
```

Now the dock widgets are not undockable and drag-able. So Is there a way to put the title bar back?

Or perhaps another (even better) way, is there a way to delegate the drag-ability (of the hidden title bar) to the whole window (which I would expect from the code fraction above, but it doesn't work that wqay) or the tab leaf?

Just to avoid some dead ends: I've tested some solutions involving dragging QTabWidget tabs, but they lacked the flexibility of tabbed QDockWidgets (like undocking it to new window and docking to different positions of the windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the default title bar to be returned, then you must pass None:

```
self.dW1.setTitleBarWidget(None)
```

Comment: Thank you, works as a charm, accepted answer. Would you know how to query the state of the  TitleBarWidget? I tried `if self.dw1.titleBarWidget == None`, but it always gives False value, regardless of the `dw1` titleBarWidget state...

Comment: @Oak_3260548 use `if self.dw1.titleBarWidget() is None:`